# How to sort after populate?

Tags: sails.js, waterline

i have the following models :

**Appgroupmodule.js**

```
module.exports = {
  autoPK: false,
  freezeTableName: true,
  autoCreatedAt: false,
  autoUpdatedAt: false,
  attributes: {
    appgroup_id:{
      model: 'Appgroup'
    },
    appmodule_id:{
      model: 'Appmodule',
      primaryKey: true
    },
    active: 'INTEGER'

  }
};
```

**Appmodule.js**

```
var uuid = require('node-uuid');

module.exports = {
  autoPK: false,
  freezeTableName: true,
  autoCreatedAt: false,
  autoUpdatedAt: false,
  attributes: {
    id: {
        type : 'uuidv4',
        primaryKey: true,
        required: true
    },
    name: 'STRING',
    url: 'STRING',
    idx: 'INTEGER',
    flag: 'INTEGER',
    deleted: 'INTEGER',
    uplink: 'STRING'

  },
  newid: function(){
    return uuid.v4();
  },
  beforeCreate: function(values,next){
    values.id = uuid.v4();
    next();
  }
};
```

and i have the following code :

```
Appgroupmodule.find({appgroup_id:req.session.user.appgroup_id,active:0})
.populateAll()
.sort({'idx':'asc'})
```

and raise an error

> Details:  Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column
>   'appgroupmodule.idx' in 'order clause'

How to sort by idx which idx is field of model Appmodule?

Answer (score 1):

```
Details: Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'appgroupmodule.idx' in 'order clause'
```

As Your error is informing that you mentioned bad field name. Here you have **idx** field in `Appmodule` and you are querying in `Appgroupmodule` so that's why adapter is throwing this error.

Now You require to sort based on `appmodule.idx` so your argument should be like this

```
Appgroupmodule.find({appgroup_id:req.session.user.appgroup_id,active:0})
.populateAll()
.sort({'appmodule_id':{'idx':'asc'}})
```